FlashLoanWithSwap
Question: I have tried to flashloan with Solidity using Aave code. The issue occurred when calling the _flashloan function with the token address and amount as arguments.
Steps:
Convert the pool address to the contract address (for the loan).
Convert the contract address to the wallet address (to receive profits).
Convert the contract address back to the pool address (to repay the loan with fees).

Transactions:
From 0x16dA4541...47406EB80 to 0x69A115d3...60fFF75F6 for 5 USDC (USDC)
From 0x69A115d3...60fFF75F6 to 0xCE0c221D...2B95Ff406 for 0.5 USDC (USDC)
From 0x69A115d3...60fFF75F6 to 0x16dA4541...47406EB80 for 5.0025 USDC (USDC)

Transaction Reference: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xae306ba2a93d1fbdb6425ef624f453f716d74d357cd2db4cf8fecf22d584925f
I noticed a loss in the contract address's tokens. Is it possible to change Step 2? If not, please let me know what steps I should follow. (I am looking to flashloan with swap using Aave or Uniswap.)
Thanks in Advance.
Code:
// contracts/FlashLoan.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import {FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/flashloan/base/FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase.sol";
import {IPoolAddressesProvider} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/interfaces/IPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import {IERC20} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/IERC20.sol";

contract FlashLoan is FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase {
    address payable owner;

    constructor(address _addressProvider)
        FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(IPoolAddressesProvider(_addressProvider))
    {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
        This function is called after your contract has received the flash loaned amount
     */
    function executeOperation(
        address asset,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 premium,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    ) external override returns (bool) {
        //
        // This contract now has the funds requested.
        // Your logic goes here.
        //

        // At the end of your logic above, this contract owes
        // the flashloaned amount + premiums.
        // Therefore ensure your contract has enough to repay
        // these amounts.

        // Approve the Pool contract allowance to *pull* the owed amount
        uint256 amountOwed = amount + premium;
        IERC20(asset).approve(address(POOL), amountOwed);

        return true;
    }

    function requestFlashLoan(address _token, uint256 _amount) public {
        address receiverAddress = address(this);
        address asset = _token;
        uint256 amount = _amount;
        bytes memory params = "";
        uint16 referralCode = 0;

        POOL.flashLoanSimple(
            receiverAddress,
            asset,
            amount,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
    }

    function getBalance(address _tokenAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
        return IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function withdraw(address _tokenAddress) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
        token.transfer(msg.sender, token.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "Only the contract owner can call this function"
        );
        _;
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}```


I don't see where you are making a call to withdraw or transferring tokens to msg.sender in the callback above, and it looks like the function in your example hash a different signature. Are you saying the code above is the exact code that produced the results above that?
